# pywinauto : impossible to keep the window in the background

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, pywinauto

I am using the pywinauto on python 3.6 to automatically control a software :

```
import pywinauto as pwa
app = pwa.Application()
app.connect(best_match='WinSpec')
```

While controlling it, I need to keep the window on the background.
My problem is that, each time I send a command, the window pop up in the foreground. For example, with this command :

```
app['WinSpec'].menu_select('File')
```

How can I solve that ?
Thank you in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Not sure it's possible when opening main menu (the reason might be on application side). Of course, you can always do `app['WinSpec'].minimize()`. But it doesn't completely solve the problem.

Comment: Yes but with this the app is flashing. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: ahk `ControlSend, Edit1, This is a line in minimized notepad., Untitled`

Answer (score 0):

I checked the source code and found line `self.ctrl.set_focus()` in `menuwrapper.py`. When I comment this out, method `menu_select` isn't working for Notepad.

So the answer is: it's improssible because `WM_COMMAND` message is handled by application only if main window is focused/active.

Partial workaround (the app will blink): `app['WinSpec'].minimize()`

Comment: Thanks for your test. And indeed it's blinking with the last solution so in this case it's maybe more convenient to let it at foreground..